# "cuando + subjunctive" and "si + subjunctive"

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras, gramática, subjuntivo

I understand when I may use "cuando + subjunctive" and what it implies. For instance:

```
cuando tenga mi perro en mis brazos, estaré feliz

cuando esté en la Luna, llamaré a mis amigos
```

I wonder, may I use the same pattern but with "si"?

```
si tenga mi perro en mis brazos, estaré feliz

si esté en la Luna, llamaré a mis amigos
```

Or will it better to use indicative with "si" in such cases?

Answer (score 1):

When used like this, *cuando* always requires the subjunctive, however *si* depends on the clause.

If you are making a general statement and not referring to a specific point in time, use *si* with the indicative in both parts of the clause. It's just the same as English.

> *Si tengo mi perro en mis brazos, estoy feliz.*
>
> If I have my dog in my arms, I am happy.
>
> *Si tenía mi perro en mis brazos, estaba feliz.*
>
> If I had my dog in my arms, I was happy.

If you are talking about specific point in time, use *si* with the subjunctive verb and the corresponding conditional. This is where Spanish differs from English (especially British English), because the subjunctive is used to talk about a hypothetical situation.

> *Si tuviera mi perro en mis brazos, estaría feliz.*
>
> If I had my dog in my arms, I would be happy.
>
> *Si hubiera tenido mi perro en mis brazos, habría estado feliz.*
>
> If I had had my dog in my arms, I would have been happy.

Comment: `si tenga mi perro en mis brazos, [estaré feliz]` -- is this correct? If yes, in which situations? How would it be translated?

Comment: `si tenga mi perro en mis brazos, [estaré feliz]` -- is this correct? If yes, in which situations? How would it be translated?

Comment: I don't think so. This website, http://grammar.spanishintexas.org/verbs/si-clauses/, says you can use 'si' with present indicative in future. It should be *si tengo mi perro en mis brazos, estaré feliz*

Answer (score 0):

Just one more thing I didn't see anyone mention in the answers. You may not use present subjunctive after "si" in this case. You would need imperfect/past subjunctive, and the other sentence would be in the conditional tense:

Si tuviera...estaria
Si estuviera...llamaria

Or you can use pluperpect subjunctive, and verb agreement/conditional for the other sentence:

Si hubiera tenido...hubiera estado/estaria
Si hubiera estado...hubiera llamado/llamaria