# Cuando + futuro

Tags: subjuntivo

I started to read phrases that contained part informing that the future action is mentioned (can be verb in the future tense or a word such as "avisame") which was also paired up with the word "cuando".

Avísame (future) **cuando** hayas terminado de hablar con tu esposa.

Podrás (future) volver al trabajo **cuando** te hayas recuperado.

*Is it a general rule that when the future is mentioned and the word "cuando" is used the next verb is going to be in subjuntivo?*

Comment: Yes, it is a general rule. As when is not a definite thing, it is indefinite.

Answer (score 0):

- "Avísame (future) **cuando** **hayas terminado**(subjuntivo pretérito perfecto) de hablar con tu esposa"(It sounds either literary or just to try to assure him there's no rush. "Please let me know when you've finished talking to your wife.")
- Avísame (future) cuando <s>has terminado(indicativo pretérito perfecto compuesto)</s> de hablar con tu esposa.
  <--I'd never say something like that.

You can also say:

- Avísame (future) cuando **termines**(subjuntivo presente) de hablar con tu esposa(with a degree of urgency, once that happens, when it does, when this occurs)
- Avísame (future) cuando <s>terminas(indicativo presente)</s> de hablar con tu esposa.
- Podrás (future) volver al trabajo **cuando** te **hayas recuperado**(subjuntivo pretérito perfecto)
- Podrás (future) volver al trabajo **cuando** te **recuperes**(subjuntivo presente)
- Podrás (future) volver al trabajo cuando te <s>recuperas(indicativo presente)</s>
- Avísame (future) **si es que** **terminas**(indicativo presente) de hablar con tu esposa(if it ever does happen, if that ever happens, if that occurs, ironically, doesn't look like he'll be done any time soon)
- Avísame (future) **si es que** <s>termines(subjuntivo presente)</s> de hablar con tu esposa
- Podrás (future) volver al trabajo **si es que** te **recuperas**(indicativo presente)
- Podrás (future) volver al trabajo **si es que** te <s>recuperes(subjuntivo presente)</s>

["cuando + subjunctive" and "si + subjunctive"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/28253/cuando-subjunctive-and-si-subjunctive)

- "Sólo cuando (yo) **tenga**(subjuntivo presente) mi perro en mis/los brazos **estaré**(indicativo futuro simple) feliz o **voy a estar** feliz".
- "Sólo cuando (yo) **tengo**(indicativo presente) mi perro en mis/los brazos **soy**(indicativo presente) feliz o **estoy**(indicativo presente) feliz".
- "Sólo cuando (ella) **tenga**(subjuntivo presente) su perro en los brazos **será**(indicativo futuro simple) feliz o **estará**(indicativo futuro simple) feliz".
- "**Si** **tuviera**(subjuntivo pretérito imperfecto) mi perro en mis/los brazos **estaría**(indicativo condicional simple) feliz.
- "**Cuando** **tenía**(indicativo pretérito imperfecto) mi perro en mis/los brazos **era**(indicativo pretérito imperfecto) feliz.
- "**Sólo cuando** **tuve**(indicativo pretérito perfecto simple) el/mi perro en mis brazos **fuí**(indicativo pretérito perfecto simple) feliz"
- Cada vez que **tenía**/Si **tenía**(indicativo pretérito imperfecto) al perro en mis brazos, **estaba**(indicativo pretérito imperfecto) feliz.
- "Se va a poner contenta (ella) **si es que** (nosotros) **recuperamos**(indicativo presente) al perro"
- "Se va a poner contenta (ella) **de que** (nosotros) **recuperemos**(subjuntivo presente) al perro"
- "Se va a poner contenta (ella) **cuando** (nosotros) **recuperemos**(subjuntivo presente) al perro"
- "Va a estar/Estará contenta de **recuperar**(infinitivo) a su perro".
- Si **hubiera tenido**(subjuntivo pretérito pluscuamperfecto) a mi perro en mis/los brazos, **habría sido**(indicativo condicional perfecto) feliz.
- Si <s>esté(subjuntivo presente)</s> en la Luna, llamaré a mis amigos.
- Si es que **estoy(indicativo presente)** en la Luna, llamaré a mis amigos.
- **Cuando** esté (subjuntivo presente) en la Luna, llamaré a mis amigos.

Comment: Do I have it correct that "si es que" automatically enables indicativo?

Comment: @sepedu87 [cuando-subjunctive-and-si-subjunctive](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/28253/cuando-subjunctive-and-si-subjunctive) "Sólo cuando tenga(subjuntivo presente) mi perro en mis/los brazos estaré(indicativo futuro simple) feliz o voy a estar feliz" || "Si tuviera(subjuntivo pretérito imperfecto) mi perro en mis/los brazos estaría(indicativo condicional simple) feliz || "Se va a poner contenta (ella) si es que (nosotros) recuperamos(indicativo presente) al perro" || "Va a estar/Estará contenta de recuperar(infinitivo) a su perro".